# Public folder contents not updating

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, public-folders

On a pristine Windows 7 install, you have these folders among others

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents
C:\Users\Public\Downloads
```

With Downloads, you can enter the folder and create a new folder

```
C:\Users\Public\Downloads\New folder
```

Then if you go back to C:\Users\Public, the Downloads folder no longer
appears empty. However, if you repeat the process with Documents, the folder
continues to appear empty. How can I fix this?

[image: docs]

Update

I tested this, and Windows 8 has the same issue.

Comment: Try using the F5 key?

Comment: I think going **Back** (keyboard `Alt+LeftArrow`) means going _to previous_ **view**, regardless of changes made in. To force explorer to read and  show contingent changes: use **Up to parent** (keyboard `Alt+UpArrow`). See also @BrandonB's comment, he's right...

Comment: With respect to my previous comment, a keyboard shortcut for commended **Up to parent** might be `BackSpace`